# Calling class method. Ambiguous type

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming

The title probably is not the clearest one but honestly I don't know what I don't know :(

There is this Clock class:

```
class Clock c where
   rate :: c → Double

data AudRate
data CtrRate
```

And instances:

```
instance Clock AudRate where
   rate _ = 44100
instance Clock CtrRate where
   rate _ = 4410
```

My function:

```
burst :: Clock p => Double -> SigFun p () Double
burst m = proc () -> do 
     burstEnv <- envLineSeg [1,1,0,0] [(m/(rate (undefined :: p))), (1/4410), (m+1/4410) ] -< ()
     noise <- noiseWhite 51 -< ()
     outA -< noise * burstEnv
```

GHC tells me that: (rate (undefined :: p))

```
Could not deduce (Clock p0) arising from a use of `rate'
from the context (Clock p)
  bound by the type signature for
             burst1 :: Clock p => Double -> SigFun p () Double
  at Karplus.hs:11:11-49
The type variable `p0' is ambiguous
```

But the same expression is used in a source code of the library I use.

```
outFileHelp :: forall a p. (AudioSample a, Clock p) => 
        ([Double] -> [Double]) -- ^ Post-processing function.
     -> String              -- ^ Filename to write to.
     -> Double              -- ^ Duration of the wav in seconds.
     -> Signal p () a       -- ^ Signal representing the sound.
     -> IO ()
outFileHelp f filepath dur sf = 
let sr          = rate (undefined :: p)
  numChannels = numChans (undefined :: a)
  numSamples  = truncate (dur * sr) * numChannels
  dat         = map (fromSample . (*0.999)) 
                    (f (toSamples dur sf)) :: [Int32]
                -- multiply by 0.999 to avoid wraparound at 1.0
  array       = listArray (0, numSamples-1) dat
  aud = Audio { sampleRate    = truncate sr,
                channelNumber = numChannels,
                sampleData    = array }
in exportFile filepath aud
```

Is it possible to use this expression in my code and make GHC compile it? Are there any extensions?

Comment: BTW, this way of passing around phantom arguments with `undefined` is risky and somewhat outdated. I would write new code with [`rate :: Tagged c Double`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.8.2/docs/Data-Tagged.html) instead. That's also a bit awkward, but definitely better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that type variables are, by default, scoped only to a single signature. I.e. when you use `p` in your function signature, the compiler won't connect this at all to the `undefined :: p` you then use in the definition. Rather, it'll think “`undefined` of some other type which also happens to be referred to as `p`“.

Fortunately, GHC *can* scope type variables to a whole function definition:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

burst :: ∀ p . Clock p => Double -> SigFun p () Double
burst m = proc () -> do 
     burstEnv <- envLineSeg [1,1,0,0] [(m/(rate (undefined :: p))), (1/4410), (m+1/4410) ] -< ()
     noise <- noiseWhite 51 -< ()
     outA -< noise * burstEnv
```

Note that the `∀ p` is mandatory (`forall a p. (AudioSample a, Clock p)`) in the example code), otherwise `ScopedTypeVariables` simply doesn't apply to this function.